# how to collect the parameters passed from the navigation page in windows phone 7 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am building an app for windows phone 7 where i am extracting a few data in my listbox from webservice. Now when the user clicks any item in the listbox it should be navigated to another page where the details about the items clicked has to be shown. Now what i did in my coding of on navigation  is shown here:

```
    public class Newss
    {
        public string News_Title { get; set; }
        public string News_Description { get; set; }
        public string Date_Start { get; set; }
        public string image_path { get; set; }
        public BitmapImage ImageBind{get;set;}

      }

   public News()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        KejriwalService.aapSoapClient client = new KejriwalService.aapSoapClient();
        client.getarvindNewsCompleted += new EventHandler<KejriwalService.getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs>(client_getarvindNewsCompleted);
        client.getarvindNewsAsync();

        progressName.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }

    void client_getarvindNewsCompleted(object sender, KejriwalService.getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string result = e.Result.ToString();
        List<Newss> listData = new List<Newss>();
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(result);

        progressName.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

       foreach (var location in doc.Descendants("UserDetails"))

       {
           Newss data = new Newss();


            data.News_Title = location.Element("News_Title").Value;
            //data.News_Description = location.Element("News_Description").Value;
            data.Date_Start = location.Element("Date_Start").Value;
            data.image_path = location.Element("image_path").Value;
            data.ImageBind = new BitmapImage(new Uri( @"http://political-leader.vzons.com/ArvindKejriwal/images/uploaded/"+data.image_path, UriKind.Absolute));

            listData.Add(data);
        }

        listBox1.ItemsSource = listData;

    }

    private void Image_Back(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AAP.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // If selected index is -1 (no selection) do nothing

        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
            return;

        Newss news = listBox1.SelectedItem as Newss;

        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NewsDetails.xaml?News_Title=" + news.News_Title + "&News_Description=" + news.News_Description + "&image_path=" + news.image_path, UriKind.Relative));

        // Reset selected index to -1 (no selection)
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

Now in the NewsDetails.xaml page i want to display all the data. Here is my NewsDetails page:

```
namespace KejriwalPhoneApp
{
public partial class NewsDetails : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public NewsDetails()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
     }

   private void Image_Back(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/News.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
}
```

NewsDetails.xaml page

```
 public NewsDetails()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var newsTitle        = NavigationContext.QueryString["News_Title"];
        var newsDescription  = NavigationContext.QueryString["News_Description"];
        var dateStart        = NavigationContext.QueryString["Date_Start"];
        var imagePath = NavigationContext.QueryString["image_path"];
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get query string parameter using `NavigationContext.QueryString`. For example :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    var newsTitle = "";
    //check if particular parameter available in uri string
    if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("News_Title"))
    {
        //if it is available, get parameter value
        newsTitle = NavigationContext.QueryString["News_Title"];
    }
}
```

Comment: i wrote your code in the page that i am navigated to i.e NewsDetails.xaml but i am getting an exception that Nullreferece. Please see the code that i wrote which gave me the exception

Comment: put it in `OnNavigatedTo` event instead of in the page constructor. NavigationContext.QueryString is not available yet at the moment constructor called.

Comment: how to display for the image. I m just getting the image name here and not the image

Comment: if you ever managed to display the image (in previous page maybe), do it the same way here. what you get (of course should be what you pass from prev page too) is path to image location. put image control in UI and load image from that path location.

Answer (score 2):

umm, try this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626521(v=vs.105).aspx

on the page you are giving parameters:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml?msg=" + textBox1.Text, UriKind.Relative));`
```

and where you receive it:

`protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)`
        `{`
            `base.OnNavigatedTo(e);`

```
        string msg = "";



        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("msg", out msg))

            textBlock1.Text = msg;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

read this post [How to perform page navigation on Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626521%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), and [Windows Phone 7 Silverlight Programming - Navigation between Pages](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Silverlight-Programming-Navigation-between-Pages.aspx)

Comment: I know how to navigate but here i need to get the values from the previous page to the page i am navigated